# Flex: Draw daisy using Degrafa. How?

Tags: apache-flex, degrafa

I'm trying to create dynamic flower component to depict relations between parent object and it's children.
Parent object is represented by daisy center and the children are represented by petals. Each of above can have a specific fill/color and text label, moreover petals should be draggable. My question is: is that possible to do using Degrafa? Can anyone post an example of drawing flower using degrafa? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  You don't want to even try? It would be better if you gave it an effort and then asked for help if you got stuck rather than asking if someone could do it for you.

Comment: Greg, sorry for that misunderstanding. Actually I have already created this component without Degrafa (in pure AS3). Of course I did try before ask and my daisy was a combination of Circle and GeometryRepeater but it wasn't dynamic. 
Ok, I'll share my code and then ask more precisely where I stuck.